# How do I add JS that when I click on yellow, a box will change its color to yellow?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.getElementById('two').onclick = function()
    {
        document.getElementById('box1').style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';   
    }
```

```css
body {
        font: 1.2em Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    #menu {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    #menu li {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 1em;
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color:aquamarine;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        width: 25%;
    }
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
```

```html
<h2 id="firstHeading">What can we code in JavaScript?</h2>

<p> Some possible changes ... </p>
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="one"> Yellow </li>
    <li id="two"> Grey  </li>
    <li id="three"> Wide border</li>
</ul>

<div id="box1"> One </div>
<div id="box2"> Two </div>

<p><button id="reset"> Reset </button></p>
```

I want to add JS that when I click on "Yellow", background of the first box is set to yellow, when I click on "Grey" the background color of both boxes is to #CCC, when the I move the mouse over "Wide border" the second box gets a border of 10px solid red and when I move the mouse off "Wide Border" returns to the original solid black". Lastly, when I click reset everything goes back to normal.

[image: Copy of the webpage]

Comment: Be sure to simplify your code and post it here so it's more convenient for people to work with, you'll get a better response that way. :)

Comment: Are you asking someone to write the code for you, or do you have code you've been trying to get working already? (the latter is preferred)

Comment: Or in other words, create a [mcve]

Comment: You have described a lot of what you want, but said nothing about what specifically you are having trouble with or what is wrong with all the code you posted. Some portion of it is working (clicking grey makes the first box become gray) so it seems you know how to do a lot of what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code could look like this.

```
var btn1 = document.querySelector('#one');
var btn2 = document.querySelector('#two');
var btn3 = document.querySelector('#three');
var btn4 = document.querySelector('#reset');
var box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');
var box2 = document.querySelector('#box2');
var initialBorder = box2.style.border;

btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    box1.style.background = 'yellow';
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    box1.style.background = '#ccc';
    box2.style.background = '#ccc';
});

btn3.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    box2.style.border = '10px solid red';
});

btn3.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    box2.style.border = initialBorder;
});

btn4.addEventListener('click', function() {
    box1.style.background = 'white';
    box2.style.background = 'white';
});
```